# How to push arrayobjects into another arrayobjects , Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying concat below array of objects in typescript:

```
data1 = [
  {"ID":"938","Name":"C6"},
  {"ID":"939","Name":"C7"},
  {"ID":"931","Name":"C9"}
]

data2 = [
  {"ID":"438","Name":"t6"},
  {"ID":"439","Name":"t7"},
  {"ID":"431","Name":"t9"}
]
```

This is the desired output:

```
output = [
  {"ID":"938","Name":"C6"},
  {"ID":"939","Name":"C7"},
  {"ID":"931","Name":"C9"},
  {"ID":"438","Name":"t6"},
  {"ID":"439","Name":"t7"},
  {"ID":"431","Name":"t9"}
]
```

Comment: Do you need to remove duplicates? Or just concatenate `data1`, `data2` and `output` together? or do you want `data1` and `data2` to be concatenated to result in `output`?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(data1,data2);
```

and you should have data1 array modified as output array.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or `...` ([spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax)) should do the work:

```js
const data1 = [{"ID":"938","Name":"C6"},{"ID":"939","Name":"C7"},{"ID":"931","Name":"C9"}];

const data2 = [{"ID":"438","Name":"t6"},{"ID":"439","Name":"t7"},{"ID":"431","Name":"t9"}];

const output = [...data1, ...data2];

console.log(output);
```